# How to write a random choice function in JES

Tags: jython, jes

How do I write a (short) function in JES to choose, and return, a random quotation from all of the quotations stored in a specific file.

```
 def readSaying():
    import random
    file=open('C:/computer course/assignment 5/assignment5sayings.txt',"rt")
    contents=file.read()
    file.close()
    random.seed()  
    print random.choice(contents)
```

Update
so it looks like by adding random.seed() it is reading my file but it is just choosing 1 letter-how do I get it to choose a whole quote
eg to choose 1 of these quotes:

1. "Any sufficiently advanced bug is indistinguishable from a feature" -     Kulawiec
2. "By the year 2020, there will be a whole new industry built on remembering the year 2000" - Alvin Toffler
3. "You can lead a boy to college, but you cannot make him think" - Elbert Hubbard
4. "Many people would rather die than think; in fact, most do" - Bertrand Russell

Comment: def readSaying():
  import random
  s=open('C:/computer course/assignment 5/assignment5sayings.txt')
  file.read(sayings)
  s=sayings  
  print random.choice(s)

Comment: It is customary to leave the original question intact otherwise if you edit your question then a valid answer gets rendered obsolete.  What you usually do is add a UPDATE section to the bottom of the question so that history is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to seed your random number generator.  Place `random.seed()` before your `random.choice(contents)`

[9.4. random — Generate pseudo-random numbers](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/random.html)

`random.seed([x])`

> Initialize the basic random number generator. Optional argument x can be any hashable object. If x is omitted or None, current system time is used; current system time is also used to initialize the generator when the module is first imported. If randomness sources are provided by the operating system, they are used instead of the system time (see the os.urandom() function for details on availability).
>
> Changed in version 2.4: formerly, operating system resources were not used.
>
> If x is not None or an int or long, hash(x) is used instead. If x is an int or long, x is used directly.